# When using removeall on a list of objects, are the objects removed from memory completely?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having some memory issues on an application I'm setting up that makes frequent use of "removeall" on a list of custom objects.  Should something be done to each of the objects to be removed before running this function to clean up any mess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RemoveAll will remove them from your collection.  If there are any other references to the objects then they will continue to exist.

You could also be using some unmanaged resources that need to be cleaned up.  Generally you would put these in a Dispose method if you're implementing IDisposable and also in a Finalize method to ensure that they are cleaned up.

Otherwise, the garbage collector will clean up any managed resources.  The only problems this can cause (and this is VERY rare) is that the garbage collector runs at a lower priority and if your processor is seriously pegged, it might not get enough cycles to clean up memory.

Comment: Thanks!.  All objects are added to the lists as they are created, ie:


`ListOfWidgets.Add(New Widget("String", value))`


I'm using something like:


`ListOfWidgets.RemoveAll(Function(x) x.alive)`


If in another area I had:


`Customer.Widget = ListofWidgets(1)`


Should I be concerned that ListofWidgets(1) doesn't get completely removed by the removeall method?



The memory issue is relatively minor, but could grow over time if I am improperly depending on removeall to do the garbage collection.

Comment: @Mason11987 You should read up a bit on GC, "roots" and reachability.  In your example, both `Customer` and `ListOfWidgets` have a reference to the same widget.  If you remove the widget from the list, and if `Customer` remains reachable from a GC root, the widget won't be eligible for collection -- and you wouldn't want it to be, since `Customer` is still using it.  Objects become eligible for collection only when they're unreachable by *any* path from a GC root, because only then can we be sure they're not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no.  Let the garbage collector do its work.

If the objects implement `IDisposable`, you might make a case for calling `Dispose` on them, but only if you know that they're not being used anywhere else.

If the lists are very large, the lists themselves are probably implicated in your problems.  Big lists are a common cause of [large object heap fragmentation](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&q=large+object+heap+fragmentation).  In that case, you don't need to concern yourself with the objects contained in the list.

If you describe your memory issues in more detail, you might get a more helpful answer.

Comment: The lists all generally have <1k items at any given time but most of those 1k items will be gone and replaced with new ones over a short timespan, so if the old ones stuck around it could cause issues.

I'm not too concerned about the memory, more about my practices and understanding of removeall.  I think you helped with that though.  Thanks